# .net MAUI can't run Android App on device or emulator

Tags: .net-maui

I have a .net maui application that I try to debug on an Android Emulator or my device. Base on the status of VS everything went fine. But after the `Deployment was successful` just nothing happens and when I check the emulator the app is not installed. It does work on my mac with the iOS target and with the windows version.
With a new created app from the .net maui template it works aswell. I tried to compare the settings but as far as I can see they are identical.
I tried the usual with deleting bin and obj, I also tried VS 2022 Preview (instead of the stable) and it's the same between my desktop and my laptop.

In case that is of any help, the project is open source. Here is the link to my fork: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows

This is the output of the Build Console:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: MoneyFox.Ui, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Starting deployment to pixel_5_-_api_31 ...
1>Deploying to pixel_5_-_api_31 ...
Build started.
Project "MoneyFox.Ui.csproj" (Install target(s)):
There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm'.
There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm64'.
There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x86'.
There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x64'.
Found Java SDK version 11.0.12.
Found Java SDK version 11.0.12.
Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.465\tools\
Android Platform API level: 31
TargetFrameworkVersion: v6.0
Android NDK: 
Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
Android SDK Build Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\
Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\
Application Java class: android.app.Application
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetMauiItems target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetMauiItems target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Skipping target "ProcessMauiSplashScreens" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "ProcessMauiFonts" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "ResizetizeImages" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_ConvertResourcesCases" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Project "MoneyFox.Ui.csproj" (_ComputeFilesToPublishForRuntimeIdentifiers target(s)):
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Core.csproj".
Project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
Done building project "MoneyFox.Infrastructure.csproj".
Done building project "MoneyFox.Ui.csproj".
Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ManifestMerger" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_BuildApkFastDev" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CopyPackage" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Touching "obj\Debug
et6.0-android\android_debug_keystore.flag".
Skipping target "_Sign" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_Upload" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Done building project "MoneyFox.Ui.csproj".
Build succeeded.
1>Deployment was successful to pixel_5_-_api_31.
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you try to use the release model?  I met the same problem when I tried to debug it, so I try to use release instead of debug and the VS showed error message about target framework.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but in release it says as well Deployment Successful without the app showing app on the emulator. Also it does build correctly on Azure Devops - or at least so it seems.

Comment: Alright I found the issue. For some reason my MainActivity was missing the  `MainLauncher = true` attribute... with that added it starts as expected. Unfortunate that there isn't some kind of warning or error that no activity was found to launch or something.